# Motor shield leaves no pins accessible

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

I just bought a motor shield for my UNO, in the pic below:

[image]

Plugging it into the uno leaves no pins accessible on the board. I’d like to use it to build a robot car, but there’s nowhere to plug in the ultrasonic sensors. Do I need to solder some pins to the row at the top of the pic, or to the through-board holes on the right labelled A0-5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [tutorial](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield), the shield uses almost all D pins. Free are pins 2 and 13. If servo is not used the pins 9 and 10 are free too. The pin 2 has the extra hole to solder a wire or a single pin header.

All analog pins are free and the shield enables to solder headers for them with additional header rows for 5V and ground for every A pin.

You can use analog pins as digital pins to connect the ultrasonic sensor.

Connection of I2C devices is possible on A4 and A5 pins.

The shield doesn't alow to stack a next shield, because it heats up.

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can solder pin headers or contact wires directly to the shield. if use pinheaders it is easier to use the pins for other purposes. 
In the case of using ultrasonic sensor you should have to use digital pins along with the 5v and ground pins of the shield.

Comment: Just avoid using already-used pins...

Comment: yes for sure @frarugi87

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Screw shield" between the motor shield and the Uno to make access to the unused pins easier.[image]